# QlikSense: Can the Filter pane object be adjusted to show one field at a time

Tags: qliksense

The Built-in Filter pane object on `QlikSense` allow users to choose from multiple fields, can we customize the Filter pane to show the user a single selection at a time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this can be done. You do it in Add-Ons > Data Handling > Calculation condition expression box.

This needs to be done on the chart that you want to limit to only 1 selection, so for a sheet you will need to do it for all charts on the sheet.

You need to return 1 or 0 for this expression as far as I know, so here is an example:

```
If(GetSelectedCount([Field]) = 1
    ,1
    ,0
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This solution is great. However, it's relevant a half. Because, user could select more than 1 choice and the chart couldn't be show in that case with a message: "The calculation condition is not fulfilled". It will be better if we can customize the filter pane to allow 1 choice only, similar to a list box. Can we edit a built-in object of Qliksense, it's html 5, then I think it's not too difficult to support a listbox object.

Comment: No prob. Yeah I get you, it is a bit of a hack, but thats kinda the way you need to treat qlik sometimes! Ok in that case the best solution would be to write your own extension I think and forget about the default list box. Its not that difficult, and once you've written one they generally stick to the same layout. You could use an existing extension like listbox v2 on qlik branch to start with and modify that, its all just javascript and some html. That would give you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, and probably not relevant now, but I had the same questions as I started using Qlik Sense this year. Depending on your integration and who is going to use it, I recommend installing an extension.

[Climbers Selection Bar](http://branch.qlik.com/#!/project/5775290349fc1bfca8047ad2) is a great option, and integrates into Qlik Sense. Alternatively you can make a mash-up in the Dev-hub, and code it in JavaScript. This require you to make a List with your Dimension and write a callback-function.

The  app.field("FieldName").selectMatch($(this).text(), false); makes sure you only select one at a time (deselecting others)

```js
 function callback(reply, app){

        //empty out the Div you've created to hold the list
        $("#DIV-ID").empty();
        //get the Object
        var qObject = reply.qListObject;
        //Loop through the data returned
        $.each(qObject.qDataPages[0].qMatrix, function() {
            //get the current item
            var item = this[0];
            //append the item to the list     
         $("#DIV-ID").append("<li><a>" + item.qText + "</a></li>");
        });
        //add the ability for the item to be clicked and selected in QlikView
        $("#DIV-ID li").click(function() {
            app.field("FieldName").selectMatch($(this).text(), false);
        });
 }
```

Comment: it's great! I'm still using Qliksense now. I'll try it when I have time. Thanks for your sharing.